# Dynamic columns in sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In some application,
I am using following sql query,

```
SELECT DATE, 
SUM( CASE WHEN project_id =  '6' THEN spent_time  ELSE 0 END ) project_1, 
SUM( CASE WHEN project_id =  '41' THEN spent_time  ELSE 0 END ) project_2, 
SUM( CASE WHEN project_id =  '14' THEN spent_time ELSE 0 END ) project_3
FROM tasks
WHERE user_id =80
GROUP BY DATE, project_id
```

it returns following output

[image]

but in the above SQL query I have used predefined columns. I am looking for a solution where I have dynamic columns say I don't have project ids known before hand.

Also I want one extra columns that shows sum of project_1, project_2, project_3 for each row.

So, the resultant structure will be DATE, PROJECT_1, PROJECT_2, PROJECT_3, SUM_OF_PROJECTS

Can I also get data where the row doesn't exists? For instance `2012-04-03` in the below example.Preferably not using calendar table

Any pointers would be appreciated.

***other details: Database- mysql, Rails(2.3.14)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write code the writes SQL. There is no way to have a single static SQL query that returns a dynamic number of columns. Only by dynamically building the query itself can you accomplish that.

Your example code is fine. For a fixed number of projects.

You could even make '6', '41' and '14' into parameters, meaning that your query will always return three projects, but they could be different projects each time.

But to then have a fourth project, you'd need to change the query.

You could write code to make that change on the fly (dynamic SQL), or just work out the most columns you ever need at once, and then live with that limitation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what database engine you're using, but the sample below uses Microsoft SQL Server. I'm sure it could be adapted quite easily to work with other engines.

To start with, I created some setup data using the following queries:

```
create table tasks(
[id] int not null identity(1,1),
[DATE] smalldatetime not null,
project_id int not null,
spent_time int not null,
primary key ([id])
)
go
insert into tasks([date],project_id,spent_time)
select '2012-04-02',1,10
union all select '2012-04-02',1,5
union all select '2012-04-02',2,5
union all select '2012-04-03',1,8
union all select '2012-04-03',2,1
go
```

As has been mentioned in comments above, you need to generate a SQL statement dynamically.  I do this into the variable @sql, before executing it at the end.  Here's my solution:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @project_id nvarchar(10)
select @sql = 'select [date]'

declare c cursor for select distinct convert(nvarchar(10),project_id) as project_id from tasks order by project_id
open c
fetch c into @project_id
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @sql = @sql + ', sum(case when project_id = ' + @project_id + ' then spent_time else 0 end) as project_' + @project_id
    fetch c into @project_id
end
close c
deallocate c

select @sql = @sql + ', sum(spent_time) as sum_of_projects from tasks group by [date] order by [date]'
exec (@sql)
```

As expected from my test data, it generates the output:

```
date        project_1  project_2
----        ---------  ---------
2012-04-02  15         5
2012-04-03  8          1
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

OP has stated a desire to avoid cursors, so the following code also works (on MS SQL Server at least) without using a cursor...

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @project_id nvarchar(10)
select @sql = 'select [date]'

select @sql = @sql + ', sum(case when project_id = ' + project_id + ' then spent_time else 0 end) as project_' + project_id
from (select distinct CONVERT(nvarchar(10), project_id) as project_id from tasks) q

select @sql = @sql + ', sum(spent_time) as sum_of_projects from tasks group by [date] order by [date]'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Note that I didn't include user_id in my example, as it's not core to the problem you have. You can easily add it back in to your implementation. :)

Comment: your answer is perfectly fine. but its difficult for me to use cursors , pl/sql in rails. currently i dont have enough knowledge for the same. for sql your solution is very useful. thnx

Comment: I've added a cursor-less solution, but can't state whether or not it will work on pl/sql I'm afraid!

Comment: Updated again to add the new requirement for a "sum_of_projects" column not in original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using pivot. Check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx for an example

Comment: Pivot still requires you to know the columns in advance.  It may make the dynamic SQL simpler, but you still need dynamic sql for dynamic columns.

Comment: yes i did go through that. could not get much. can you show an example for my case. that will be of great help